# Grocery Crud callback after update not sending email

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I'm fairly new to CI and GC, so my problem might just be syntax issues. I'm trying to send an email to the owner of the record after update of a record by an administrator. The email to administrator on insert works, but the email to the user on update does nothing.

Email functions in controller:

```
public function email_admin_vehicle()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Admin');
        $this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');

        $this->email->subject('New Vehicle Added');
        $this->email->message('A new vehicle has been registered. Please log in to your admin panel to approve the vehicle.');

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
     public function email_user_vehicle($post_array)
    {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Cars in the Park');
        $this->email->to($post_array['email']);

        $this->email->subject('Vehicle Updated');
        $this->email->message('An administrator has updated your vehicle details. Please log on to your account to view the changes.');

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

Callbacks and CG functions:

```
//==================\\
    //START: Vehicle Crud
    //==================\\
    public function vehicle()
    {
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            redirect('auth/login');
        }
        else {
            if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
        // Get User_id if standard user
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        // Build Crud
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
            $crud->unset_jquery();
            // Timestamps
            $crud->set_model('MY_grocery_Model');
            // Table
            $crud->set_table('vehicle');
            // Special Queries
            $crud->where('vehicle.user_id', $user->id );
            // Display Rules
            $crud->display_as('registration','Licence Plate'); 
            $crud->display_as('user_id','Name');
            $crud->display_as('event_id','Event');
            $crud->display_as('stand_id','Stand');
            $crud->display_as('club_id','Club');
            // Relations
            $crud->set_relation('event_id','event','event_name');
            $crud->set_relation('user_id','users','username');
            $crud->set_relation('club_id','club','club_name');
            $crud->set_relation('stand_id','stand','code');
            // Validation
            $crud->set_rules('year','Year','integer');
            $crud->required_fields('make','model','year','country','registration','event','club');
            // Fields Rules
            $crud->unset_add_fields('created','updated','stand_id','verified','paid','user_id','ref_number');
            $crud->unset_edit_fields('created','updated','stand_id','verified','paid','user_id','ref_number');
            $crud->unset_columns('user_id','created','updated','verified','paid');
            $crud->unset_export();
            $crud->unset_print();
            // Adding Buttons
            $crud->add_action('Print', '', 'print/single','ui-icon-print');
            // Callbacks
            $crud->callback_after_update(array($this, 'email_user_vehicle'));
            // Render
            $output = $crud->render();
            $this->_cruds_output($output);   


        }
        else {
                $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
                $crud->unset_jquery();
                // Timestamps
                $crud->set_model('MY_grocery_Model');
                // Table
                $crud->set_table('vehicle');
                // Special Queries
                // Display Rules
                $crud->display_as('registration','Licence Plate');
                $crud->display_as('user_id','Name');
                $crud->display_as('event_id','Event');
                $crud->display_as('stand_id','Stand');
                $crud->display_as('club_id','Club');
                // Relations
                $crud->set_relation('event_id','event','event_name');
                $crud->set_relation('user_id','users','username');
                $crud->set_relation('club_id','club','club_name');
                $crud->set_relation('stand_id','stand','code');
                // Adding Buttons


                $crud->add_action('Print', base_url().'/assets/img/print.png', 'printforms/single','');
                // Unset Fields
                $crud->unset_add_fields('created','updated','user_id','ref_number');
                $crud->unset_edit_fields('created','updated','user_id','ref_number');
                // Callbacks
                //$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'add_new_club_user'));
                $crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'email_admin_vehicle'));
                //$crud->callback_after_update(array($this, 'email_user_vehicle'));


                // Render
                $output = $crud->render();
                $this->_cruds_output($output);   
            } 

        }  
    }
```

As I said it might just be that I don't know what I'm doing at all, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$crud->callback_after_update(array($this, 'email_user_vehicle'));` and `$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'email_admin_vehicle'));` where swapped around. The code works as is with the 2 statements swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you're using Linux, it'll have a built in mail server, but for my case, I'm on Windows with Wamp, which is not having a built in mail server. Therefore I'm using phpmailer.

I didn't see you set the SMTP host and port.
I use CI but not using its email library, though I find it much simpler than i thought using native PHP.

My code looks like this:

```
public function send_confirmation($grocery_no)
{
    require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/class.smtp.php');


    $order = $this->Grocery_model($grocery_no);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = '/*your_email_here*/@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '/*your_password_here*/';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->From = '/*your_email_here*/';
    $mail->FromName = '/*your_name_here*/';
    $mail->AddAddress($order['contact_email']);

    $mail->AddReplyTo('/*your_email_here*/', 'Admin');

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject      = "Your Grocery is Confirmed";
    $mail->AltBody      = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->Body         = "
        Hello,
    <br>
    <br>Thank you for shopping with us.
    <br>Below is your grocery list.
    <br>Have a nice day.
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Regards,
    <br>
    <br>
    ";
}
```